# Reactive java to convert Mono Object to Object without block();

Tags: java, spring-boot, project-reactor

Please help me to convert `Mono<RulesEngineResponse>` to `RulesEngineResponse` without `block();`
Currently I'm using `block()` here.

```java
public RulesEngineResponse prepareResponse(Result rulesResponse) {
    RulesEngineResponse rulesEngineResponse = rulesEngineService(data).block();
}

public Mono < RulesEngineResponse > rulesEngineService(AggregatedMessage input) {
    return WebClient.builder()
        .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        .build()
        .post()
        .uri(this.rulesEngineUrl)
        .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(input))
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE)
        .exchange()
        .flatMap(clientResponse - > clientResponse.toEntity(RulesEngineResponse.class)
            .map(responseEntity - > responseEntity.getBody()));
}
```

Comment: why? either you have a reactive use case for the service and it should call `rulesEngineService` directly and deal with the `Mono<RulesEngineResponse>`, or you have a blocking use case and it is acceptable to `block()` on that same `Mono`...

Answer (score 0):

you could use `toFuture()` method as below:

```
RulesEngineResponse rulesEngineResponse = rulesEngineService(data).toFuture().get();
```